# All subrings of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ are ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

My book says the following statments are equivalent and says they're trivial to prove, but I'm not seeing it:

(i) $I$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}_m$

(ii)  $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_m$

(iii) there is $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $d|m$ and $I = <d>$

I can see (ii) $\Rightarrow$ (i) because all ideals are subrings. Can't see any of the others though. Also, my definition of ring doesn't require the product to have an identity (so, a rng in some books, I think); and I've never talked of cyclic groups or rings.

Comment: You mean following statements are "equivalent"?

Comment: For (ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iii): the inverse image of $I$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, so it must be generated by some $d \ge 0$; and then $m \in \langle d \rangle$...

Answer (score 0):

The hard step here is (i) implies (iii) because if $I = \langle d \rangle$ then $I$ is an ideal so (iii) implies (ii) (you may want to slow down and think about this).

So let $I$ be a subring of $\mathbf{Z}_m$. View the elements of $\mathbf{Z}_m$ as the symbols $0,1,\dots,m - 1$. Let $d \in I$ be the smallest element of $1,\dots,m - 1$ in $I$. If no such $d$ exists then $I = \langle 0 \rangle$. Otherwise, we will see that $I = \langle d \rangle$ and $d \mid m$.

Certainly $d \mid m$ because otherwise take $n \in \mathbf{Z}$ such that $nd < m < (n + 1)d$ then $(n + 1)d < m + d$ so $d' = (n + 1)d - m \in I$ is a smaller element of $1,\dots,m-1$ than $d$, a contradiction.

We also know that $\langle d \rangle$ is a subring of $I$. Suppose there is an element $y \in I \setminus \langle d \rangle$. Then as before, let $n \in \mathbf{Z}$ such that $nd < y < (n + 1)d$ and then $(n + 1)d - y$ is a smaller element of $1,\dots,m-1$ in $I$ than $d$. Again, this is a contradiction.

Therefore $I = \langle d \rangle$ and $d \mid m$.

---

*Remark:* Note that since we are working with the integers, subrings and ideals are the same thing. Indeed, being an ideal is the same as being closed under multiplication by integers and multiplication by integers is the same thing as repeated addition and possibly taking negatives. Since subrings are closed under repeated addition and negatives, all subrings are ideals.